# Virtual Subdirectories with NGINX

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, location, subdirectory

I have tested my NGINX config and can successfully load my static assets, rewrites, etc at www.site.com at path /srv/public_html

Now, what I am trying to do is pass virtual subdirectories that are accessible at www.site.com/us, www.site.com/ca, www.site.com/fr-ca, etc.. and have them inherit the rules that I already have in place and behave as if the document root is /src/public_html.

I have tried appending the code below and the site is passed through the root index.php, however, my static assets are lost in the rewrite.

```
location ~ ^\/((?<currentSite>us|us-es|ca|fr-ca|en-gb|fr|hz-hans|ja)\/) { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteVirtualSubDirectories;
}

location @rewriteVirtualSubDirectories {
    rewrite ^\/((?<currentSite>us|us-es|ca|fr-ca|en-gb|fr|hz-hans|ja)\/)? /index.php?args;
}

location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404; # if reference to php executable is invalid return 404
    expires off;
    fastcgi_pass php-fpm;
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers    4 256k;

    limit_req zone=php burst=20 nodelay;

    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param UNIQUE_ID $connection.$connection_requests;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $http_x_ssl_offloaded if_not_empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this resolved the issue:

**Remove:**

```
location ~ ^\/((?<currentSite>us|us-es|ca|fr-ca|en-gb|fr|hz-hans|ja)\/) { 
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewriteVirtualSubDirectories;
}

location @rewriteVirtualSubDirectories {
    rewrite ^\/((?<currentSite>us|us-es|ca|fr-ca|en-gb|fr|hz-hans|ja)\/)? /index.php?args;
}
```

**Add at the `server` scope:**

```
rewrite ^\/(?<currentSite>us|us-es|ca|fr-ca|en-gb|fr|hz-hans|ja)(?<realPath>.*)$  $realPath break;
```